# Karate UI: Can a separate file having a scenario written in plain English be mapped to Karate feature file

Tags: karate

like Cucumber, where we write scenarios/test cases in the form of feature file in Gherkin/plain English language which can be understood by non-technical stakeholders also and those steps have corresponding code in stepdefinitions. In Karate we do not have such concept like stepdefinitions and everything is written in a feature file, so feature file becomes more of technical/ having syntax. Is there any such feature/workaround in Karate so that I can have scenarios in plain/English text and then those can be mapped to the feature file?? Thanks.